# Peano-Jordan measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A_n=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I have to show that 
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}\dots\}
\end{equation}
is Peano-Jordan measurable.

Indicate with $m_i$ the inner Peano-Jordan measure and with $m_e$ the outer Peano-Jordan measure.
Now, since 
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_nA_n\subset[0,1]
\end{equation}

$m_e\big(\bigcup_nA_n\big)\le m_e([0,1])=1$ $\quad$ and$\quad$$m_i\big(\bigcup_nA_n\big)\le m_i([0,1])=1$.

From the definition
\begin{equation}
m_i\big(\cup_n A_n\big)\le m_e\big(\cup_n A_n\big).
\end{equation}

From these considerations, how can I show that $\cup_n A_n$ is Peano-Jordan measurable?

Thanks!